# Android - Creating Multiple Levels of Tabs for ActionBar Using ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

How can I handle Android tabs in an ActionBar such that it presents multiple contextual levels of tabs and associated fragments to the user (in other words, I want the ActionBar tabs to change from one level to another based on the selections at the higher level - sort of like a hierarchical menu).  (Ideally, the solution would support an arbitrary number of "levels", but at least three "levels" would be nice)

NOTE:  For proper order to the answers, sort by "oldest" - this puts the parts in the right place with the HomeActivity last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my example of a tabs class called ABTabsAdapter class that presents and manages up to three virtual levels of tabs with associated fragments using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, ViewPager and ActionBar all working together with a collection of Tabs and Fragments "glued" together with a TabInfo structure.  This solution is pieced together from other solutions posted on StackOverflow and the Android support literature.  The key is to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter (NOT FragmentPagerAdapter as stated in the Android lit and as presented in the default Android project template).  Also, note the use of the bIsSet boolean variable which presents tabs from being selected on insert via the addTab function.  Finally, be aware that the getItemPosition function can also return the fragment/view/tab's actual position, but this has little impact on the performance of a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and it is easier to read/use when it simply returns POSITION_NONE for all items requested (this is, in fact, currently the suggested means for updating the ViewPager when tabs change place - in this implementation not only will the tabs change place, they will also be removed and re-added depending on the contextual "level" of the tabs menu.)  (Part 1)

```
public class ABTabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
{
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevelHome = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_2 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_3 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_4 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_2_1 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_2_2 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_2_3 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_3_1 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_3_1_1 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_3_2 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_3_2_1 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_3_3 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_3_3_1 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_4_1 = null;
    ActionBar.Tab tabLevel1_4_2 = null;

    TabInfo infoLevelHome = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_2 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_3 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_4 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_2_1 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_2_2 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_2_3 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_3_1 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_3_1_1 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_3_2 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_3_2_1 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_3_3 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_3_3_1 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_4_1 = null;
    TabInfo infoLevel1_4_2 = null;

    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    Boolean bIsSet = false;

    static final class TabInfo
    {
        private final Class<?> clss;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class)
        {
            clss = _class;
        }
    }

    public ABTabsAdapter(HomeActivity homeActivity, FragmentManager fragmentManager, ViewPager viewPager, ActionBar actionBar)
    {
        super(fragmentManager);
        mContext = homeActivity;
        mActionBar = actionBar;
        mViewPager = viewPager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        initializeTabs();
        bIsSet = true;
        selectLayout(0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int nPos)
    {
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, getSelectedTab(nPos).clss.getName(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object objGet)
    {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int nPos, float fOffset, int nOffsetPixels)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int nPos)
    {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(nPos);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int nState)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tabSelected, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
    {
        TabInfo infoGet = (TabInfo)tabSelected.getTag();

        selectLayout(tabSelected.getPosition());

        for (int nCount=0; nCount < mTabs.size(); nCount++)
        {
            if (mTabs.get(nCount).clss.getName() == infoGet.clss.getName())
            {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(nCount);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tabAdd, int nPos)
    {
        try
        {
            if(nPos < 0)
            {
                mTabs.add((TabInfo)tabAdd.getTag());
                mActionBar.addTab(tabAdd);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                mTabs.add(nPos,(TabInfo)tabAdd.getTag());
                mActionBar.addTab(tabAdd, nPos);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            appContext.showMessage("Error","[addTab]: "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void removeTab(ActionBar.Tab tabRemove)
    {
        try
        {
            Object tag = tabRemove.getTag();

            for (int nCount=0; nCount < mTabs.size(); nCount++)
            {
                if (mTabs.get(nCount) == tag)
                {
                    mTabs.remove(nCount);
                    mActionBar.removeTab(tabRemove);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            appContext.showMessage("Error","[removeTab]: "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void initializeTabs()
    {
        try
        {
            tabLevelHome = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevelHome != null)
            {
                tabLevelHome.setText(" Home");
                tabLevelHome.setIcon(R.drawable.levelhome_44x29);
                tabLevelHome.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevelHome = new TabInfo(HomeActivity.HomeFragment.class);
                tabLevelHome.setTag(infoLevelHome);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Home tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_2 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_2 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_2.setText(" Level1_2");
                tabLevel1_2.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_2_44x29);
                tabLevel1_2.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_2 = new TabInfo(Level1_2Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_2.setTag(infoLevel1_2);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_2 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_3 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_3 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_3.setText(" Level1_3");
                tabLevel1_3.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_3_44x29);
                tabLevel1_3.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_3 = new TabInfo(Level1_3Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_3.setTag(infoLevel1_3);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_3 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_4 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_4 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_4.setText(" Level1_4");
                tabLevel1_4.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_4_44x29);
                tabLevel1_4.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_4 = new TabInfo(Level1_4Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_4.setTag(infoLevel1_4);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_4 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_2_1 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_2_1 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_2_1.setText(" Level1_2_1");
                tabLevel1_2_1.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_2_1_44x29);
                tabLevel1_2_1.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_2_1 = new TabInfo(Level1_2_1Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_2_1.setTag(infoLevel1_2_1);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_2_1 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_2_2 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_2_2 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_2_2.setText(" Level1_2_2");
                tabLevel1_2_2.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_2_2_44x29);
                tabLevel1_2_2.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_2_2 = new TabInfo(Level1_2_2Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_2_2.setTag(infoLevel1_2_2);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_2_2 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_2_3 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_2_3 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_2_3.setText(" Level1_2_3");
                tabLevel1_2_3.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_2_3_44x29);
                tabLevel1_2_3.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_2_3 = new TabInfo(Level1_2_3Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_2_3.setTag(infoLevel1_2_3);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_2_3 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_3_1 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_3_1 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_3_1.setText(" Level1_3_1");
                tabLevel1_3_1.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_3_1_44x29);
                tabLevel1_3_1.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_3_1 = new TabInfo(Level1_3_1Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_3_1.setTag(infoLevel1_3_1);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_3_1 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_3_1_1 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_3_1_1 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_3_1_1.setText(" Level1_3_1_1");
                tabLevel1_3_1_1.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_3_1_1_44x29);
                tabLevel1_3_1_1.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_3_1_1 = new TabInfo(Level1_3_1_1Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_3_1_1.setTag(infoLevel1_3_1_1);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_3_1_1 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_3_2 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_3_2 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_3_2.setText(" Level1_3_2");
                tabLevel1_3_2.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_3_2_44x29);
                tabLevel1_3_2.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_3_2 = new TabInfo(Level1_3_2Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_3_2.setTag(infoLevel1_3_2);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_3_2 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_3_2_1 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_3_2_1 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_3_2_1.setText(" Level1_3_2_1");
                tabLevel1_3_2_1.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_3_2_1_44x29);
                tabLevel1_3_2_1.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_3_2_1 = new TabInfo(Level1_3_2_1Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_3_2_1.setTag(infoLevel1_3_2_1);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_3_2_1 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_3_3 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_3_3 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_3_3.setText(" Level1_3_3");
                tabLevel1_3_3.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_3_3_44x29);
                tabLevel1_3_3.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_3_3 = new TabInfo(Level1_3_3Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_3_3.setTag(infoLevel1_3_3);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_3_3 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_3_3_1 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_3_3_1 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_3_3_1.setText(" Level1_3_3_1");
                tabLevel1_3_3_1.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_3_3_1_44x29);
                tabLevel1_3_3_1.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_3_3_1 = new TabInfo(Level1_3_3_1Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_3_3_1.setTag(infoLevel1_3_3_1);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_3_3_1 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_4_1 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_4_1 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_4_1.setText(" Level1_4_1");
                tabLevel1_4_1.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_4_1_44x29);
                tabLevel1_4_1.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_4_1 = new TabInfo(Level1_4_1Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_4_1.setTag(infoLevel1_4_1);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_4_1 tab is not set.");

            tabLevel1_4_2 = mActionBar.newTab();
            if(tabLevel1_4_2 != null)
            {
                tabLevel1_4_2.setText(" Level1_4_2");
                tabLevel1_4_2.setIcon(R.drawable.level1_4_2_44x29);
                tabLevel1_4_2.setTabListener(this);

                infoLevel1_4_2 = new TabInfo(Level1_4_2Fragment.class);
                tabLevel1_4_2.setTag(infoLevel1_4_2);
            }
            else
                appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs] Level1_4_2 tab is not set.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            appContext.showMessage("Error","[initializeTabs]: "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void selectLayout(int nPos)
    {
        try
        {
            if(bIsSet)
            {
                bIsSet = false;

                if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == 0)
                    showLayoutHome();
                else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_levelhome)
                {
                    if(nPos == 0)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_levelhome;
                    else if(nPos == 1)
                        showLayoutLevel1_2();
                    else if(nPos == 2)
                        showLayoutLevel1_3();
                    else if(nPos == 3)
                        showLayoutLevel1_4();
                }
                else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2)
                {
                    if(nPos == 0)
                        showLayoutHome();
                    else if(nPos == 1)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_2;
                    else if(nPos == 2)
                        showLayoutLevel1_2_1();
                    else if(nPos == 3)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_4_2;
                }
                else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3)
                {
                    if (nPos == 0)
                        showLayoutHome();
                    else if (nPos == 1)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3;
                    else if (nPos == 2)
                        showLayoutLevel1_3_1();
                    else if (nPos == 3)
                        showLayoutLevel1_3_2();
                    else if (nPos == 4)
                        showLayoutLevel1_3_3();
                }
                else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4_1))
                {
                    if (nPos == 0)
                        showLayoutHome();
                    else if(nPos == 1)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_4;
                    else if(nPos == 2)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_4_1;
                    else if(nPos == 3)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_4_2;
                }
                else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1_1))
                {
                    if (nPos == 0)
                        showLayoutLevel1_3();
                    else if(nPos == 1)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1;
                    else if(nPos == 2)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1_1;
                }
                else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2_1))
                {
                    if (nPos == 0)
                        showLayoutLevel1_3();
                    else if(nPos == 1)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2;
                    else if(nPos == 2)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2_1;
                }
                else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3_1))
                {
                    if (nPos == 0)
                        showLayoutLevel1_3();
                    else if(nPos == 1)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3;
                    else if(nPos == 2)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3_1;
                }
                else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_1) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_2) ||(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_3))
                {
                    if (nPos == 0)
                        showLayoutLevel1_2();
                    else if(nPos == 1)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_2_1;
                    else if(nPos == 2)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_2_2;
                    else if(nPos == 3)
                        appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_2_3;
                }
                else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4_2)
                {
                    if(mActionBar.getTabAt(1).getText() == " Level1_2")
                    {
                        if(nPos == 0)
                            showLayoutHome();
                        else if(nPos == 1)
                            appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_2;
                        else if(nPos == 2)
                            showLayoutLevel1_2_1();
                        else if(nPos == 3)
                            appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_4_2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (nPos == 0)
                            showLayoutHome();
                        else if(nPos == 1)
                            appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_4;
                        else if(nPos == 2)
                            appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_4_1;
                        else if(nPos == 3)
                            appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_4_2;
                    }
                }
                updateActionBar();

                bIsSet = true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            appContext.showMessage("Error","[selectLayout]: "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    public TabInfo getSelectedTab(int nPos)
    {
        TabInfo infoGet = null;

        try
        {
            if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == 0)
                infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevelHome.getTag();
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_levelhome)
            {
                if(nPos == 0)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevelHome.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 1)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_2.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 2)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 3)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_4.getTag();
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2)
            {
                if(nPos == 0)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevelHome.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 1)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_2.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 2)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_2_1.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 3)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_4_2.getTag();
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3)
            {
                if (nPos == 0)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevelHome.getTag();
                else if (nPos == 1)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3.getTag();
                else if (nPos == 2)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3_1.getTag();
                else if (nPos == 3)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3_2.getTag();
                else if (nPos == 4)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3_3.getTag();
            }
            else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4_1))
            {
                if (nPos == 0)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevelHome.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 1)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_4.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 2)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_4_1.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 3)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_4_2.getTag();
            }
            else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1_1))
            {
                if (nPos == 0)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 1)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3_1.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 2)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3_1_1.getTag();
            }
            else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2_1))
            {
                if (nPos == 0)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 1)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3_2.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 2)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3_2_1.getTag();
            }
            else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3_1))
            {
                if (nPos == 0)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 1)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3_3.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 2)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_3_3_1.getTag();
            }
            else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_1) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_2) ||(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_3))
            {
                if (nPos == 0)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_2.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 1)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_2_1.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 2)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_2_2.getTag();
                else if(nPos == 3)
                    infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_2_3.getTag();
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4_2)
            {
                if(mActionBar.getTabAt(1).getText() == " Level1_2")
                {
                    if(nPos == 0)
                        infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevelHome.getTag();
                    else if(nPos == 1)
                        infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_2.getTag();
                    else if(nPos == 2)
                        infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_2_1.getTag();
                    else if(nPos == 3)
                        infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_4_2.getTag();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (nPos == 0)
                        infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevelHome.getTag();
                    else if(nPos == 1)
                        infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_4.getTag();
                    else if(nPos == 2)
                        infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_4_1.getTag();
                    else if(nPos == 3)
                        infoGet = (TabInfo)tabLevel1_4_2.getTag();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            appContext.showMessage("Error","[getSelectedTab]: "+e.toString());
        }

        return infoGet;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Part 2...

```
public void selectUpLayout()
{
    try
    {
        if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_levelhome) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4_1) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4_2))
            showLayoutHome();
        else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1_1) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2_1) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3_1))
            showLayoutLevel1_3();
        else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_1) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_2) ||(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_3))
            showLayoutLevel1_2();
        updateActionBar();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        appContext.showMessage("Error","[selectUpLayout]: "+e.toString());
    }
}

private void updateActionBar()
{
    try
    {
        if(mActionBar != null)
        {
            if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_levelhome)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("levelhome");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("levelhome");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("fragment_level1_2");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("fragment_level1_2");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("fragment_level1_3");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("fragment_level1_3");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("fragment_level1_4");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("fragment_level1_4");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_1)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_2_1");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_2_1");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_2)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_2_2");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_2_2");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2_3)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_2_3");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_2_3");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_3_1");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_3_1");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1_1)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_3_1_1");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_3_1_1");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_3_2");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_3_2");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2_1)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_3_2_1");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_3_2_1");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_3_3");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_3_3");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3_1)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_3_3_1");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_3_3_1");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4_1)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_4_1");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_4_1");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4_2)
            {
                mActionBar.setTitle("Level1_4_2");
                mActionBar.setSubtitle("Level1_4_2");
                mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        appContext.showMessage("Error","[AddTab]: "+e.toString());
    }
}

private void showLayoutHome()
{
    try
    {
        if(mActionBar != null)
        {
            if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == 0)
            {
                appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_levelhome;
                addTab(tabLevelHome,-1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_2, -1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_3,-1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_4, -1);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_2)
            {
                appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_levelhome;
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));

                addTab(tabLevel1_3,-1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_4, -1);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_3)
            {
                appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_levelhome;
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(4));
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(1));

                addTab(tabLevel1_2, -1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_3,-1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_4, -1);
            }
            else if((appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4) || (appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4_1))
            {
                appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_levelhome;
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));

                addTab(tabLevel1_2,1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_3, 2);
            }
            else if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_level1_4_2)
            {
                if(mActionBar.getTabAt(1).getText() == " Level1_2")
                {
                    appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_levelhome;
                    removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
                    removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));

                    addTab(tabLevel1_3,-1);
                    addTab(tabLevel1_4, -1);
                }
                else
                {
                    appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_levelhome;
                    removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
                    removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));

                    addTab(tabLevel1_2,1);
                    addTab(tabLevel1_3, 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        appContext.showMessage("Error","[showLayoutHome]: "+e.toString());
    }
}

private void showLayoutLevel1_2()
{
    try
    {
        if(mActionBar != null)
        {
            if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_levelhome)
            {
                appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_2;
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));

                addTab(tabLevel1_2_1,-1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_4_2, -1);
            }
            else
            {
                appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_2;
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));

                addTab(tabLevelHome,0);
                addTab(tabLevel1_4_2, -1);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        appContext.showMessage("Error","[showLayoutLevel1_2]: "+e.toString());
    }
}

private void showLayoutLevel1_3()
{
    try
    {
        if(mActionBar != null)
        {
            if(appContext.nCurrentLayoutID == R.layout.fragment_levelhome)
            {
                appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3;
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(1));

                addTab(tabLevel1_3_1, -1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_3_2,-1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_3_3, -1);
            }
            else
            {
                appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3;
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));
                removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(1));

                addTab(tabLevelHome,0);
                addTab(tabLevel1_3_1, -1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_3_2,-1);
                addTab(tabLevel1_3_3, -1);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        appContext.showMessage("Error","[showLayoutLevel1_3]: "+e.toString());
    }
}

private void showLayoutLevel1_4()
{
    try
    {
        if(mActionBar != null)
        {
            appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_4;
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(1));

            addTab(tabLevel1_4_1,-1);
            addTab(tabLevel1_4_2, -1);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        appContext.showMessage("Error","[showLayoutLevel1_4]: "+e.toString());
    }
}

private void showLayoutLevel1_2_1()
{
    try
    {
        if(mActionBar != null)
        {
            appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_2_1;
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(0));

            addTab(tabLevel1_2_2,-1);
            addTab(tabLevel1_2_3, -1);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        appContext.showMessage("Error","[showLayoutLevel1_2_1]: "+e.toString());
    }
}

private void showLayoutLevel1_3_1()
{
    try
    {
        if(mActionBar != null)
        {
            appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3_1;
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(4));
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(0));

            addTab(tabLevel1_3_1_1, -1);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        appContext.showMessage("Error","[showLayoutLevel1_3_1]: "+e.toString());
    }
}

private void showLayoutLevel1_3_2()
{
    try
    {
        if(mActionBar != null)
        {
            appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3_2;
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(4));
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(0));

            addTab(tabLevel1_3_2_1, -1);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        appContext.showMessage("Error","[showLayoutLevel1_3_2]: "+e.toString());
    }
}

private void showLayoutLevel1_3_3()
{
    try
    {
        if(mActionBar != null)
        {
            appContext.nCurrentLayoutID = R.layout.fragment_level1_3_3;
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(3));
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(2));
            removeTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(0));

            addTab(tabLevel1_3_3_1,-1);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        appContext.showMessage("Error","[showLayoutLevel1_3_3]: "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is the HomeActivity with HomeFragment code that initializes and displays it all... all you have to do is create the appContext (find this simple solution on StackOverflow) and the remaining fragments, which you should rename to be meaningful to your solution...

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        Level1_2Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_3Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_4Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_2_1Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_2_2Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_2_3Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_3_1Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_3_1_1Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_3_2Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_3_2_1Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_3_3Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_3_3_1Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_4_1Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Level1_4_2Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener
{
    ABTabsAdapter mABTabsAdapter = null;
    ActionBar mActionBar = null;
    ViewPager mViewPager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager_home);
        setContentView(mViewPager);

        mABTabsAdapter = new ABTabsAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), mViewPager, mActionBar);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            //mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("currentTab", 0));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("currentTab", mActionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    public void onFragmentInteraction()
    {
    }

    public static class HomeFragment extends Fragment
    {
        public static HomeFragment newInstance()
        {
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        public HomeFragment()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```